# Is it possible to get Radio Resource Control (RRC) state from iPhone device programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to know if it's possible to get info about RRC state in my app on iPhone. I found this thread: http://www.howardforums.com/printthread.php?t=1436705&pp=30, where they're calling specific number and they get Field Test screen and you can find there RRC state but I need to do it programmatically. RRC states: CELL_DCH (Dedicated Channel), CELL_FACH (Forward access channel), CELL_PCH (Cell Paging channel) and URA_PCH (URA Paging channel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no public API available.

Comment: So is there any hidden or private API available for this?